# How to get the data with the same name on my database but different creator using php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve the data on my table using php with the condition `if same creator and same account name then print`. I was using this code:

```
$groups = \App\Group::where('created_by', '=', $grp->created_by)->get();
  if($groups->count() > 0){
    $group = \App\Group::where('account_name', 'LIKE', $groups[0]->account_name)->groupBy('name')->get();
  }
```

But it only show the datas with the same `account_name` even though they have different creator `created_by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to delete this question because I solved this myself but I'll just post my solution. Somebody might need it:

```
$group = \App\Group::where('account_name', '=', $grp->account_name)->where('created_by', 'LIKE', $grp->created_by)->groupBy('name')->get();
```